# 2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found when calling Class Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to reach another Class in Flutter.

I have made the Class an object in my main.dart

I have am then trying to call it and having issues.

I receive the error `2 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.`. This is becuase in the Class I define `HereMapController` & `ShowDialogFunction2`. I can't work out how to link them. Any help appreciated.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
} 

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  HereMapController? hereMapController;
  ShowDialogFunction2? showDialogCallback2;



Future<void> intermodalRouter() async{
...
       final MapItemsExample2 _mapItemsExample2 = MapItemsExample2();        //Issue Here

       _sendIntermodalDataToSecondScreen(context, mappedValues, dest);     //Works Fine
       _mapItemsExample2.showFirstPolylineMapMarkers(deplat, deplong, deplocname);      //This is trying to reach other Class
      }
    });
  }
```

```
typedef ShowDialogFunction2 = void Function(RichText title, RichText message);

class MapItemsExample2 {
  final ShowDialogFunction2 _showDialog2;
  final HereMapController _hereMapController;

 MapItemsExample2(ShowDialogFunction2 showDialogCallback2, HereMapController hereMapController)
      : _showDialog2 = showDialogCallback2,
        _hereMapController = hereMapController {
...
```

When I hover over the issue line it defines Class `MapItemsExample2` as

```
(new) MapItemsExample2 MapItemsExample2(void Function(RichText, RichText) showDialogCallback2, HereMapController hereMapController)
```

I changed it to the following and no errors show. Then on running it calls `null`. I know i have set this up wrong but I just need to be able to reach the other Class

```
       final MapItemsExample2 _mapItemsExample2 = MapItemsExample2(showDialogCallback2!, hereMapController!);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a constructor for the class `MapItemsExample2` with not arguments, since you have added a constructer with two arguments you cannot use the default constructor. The solution would be to create a constructer with no arguments in addition to to your "two arguments" constructor and make your variables `late` if you don't want them initialized in the second constructor like:

```
class MapItemsExample2 {
  late ShowDialogFunction2 _showDialog2;
  late HereMapController _hereMapController;

 MapItemsExample2(ShowDialogFunction2 showDialogCallback2, HereMapController hereMapController)
      : _showDialog2 = showDialogCallback2,
        _hereMapController = hereMapController {}
    
MapItemsExample2.empty()
{
//this is the second empty constructor
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if i paste that below it says ```The default constructor is already defined.
Try giving one of the constructors a name.``` and ```All final variables must be initialized, but '_hereMapController' and '_showDialog2' aren't.``` Does this mean I still need to define the vars in the 2nd? Thanks

Comment: Okay thanks, that removes the first issue but it still shows ```All final variables must be initialized, but '_hereMapController' and '_showDialog2' aren't.``` I can add them in to remove the issue here but then I still have the original problem in main.dart. Is there a way to remove them? Thanks

Comment: as I mentioned in the answer you should remove the `final` and replace it with `late` 

and that's of course depends on your logic if it would be doable or not. if the rest of the class depends on those values, then you need to initiate these variables in the constructor, if not, you can keep them uninitialized.